# Remix: Bytecode isn't working, when deploying it with myetherwallet

Tags: remix, crowdsale

The bytecode from Remix isn't just working, it isn't deploying the contract. As far what I've known, there's something to do with the code that I've to minimize. Is there something that I has to do? I tried to run the contract on remix but it said " This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created." Might think it have to do with

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to put only the content of object, ie `6080604052336000806101..`.

Comment: Cheers. This one did fix the problem. Easy but as other replies differently to the same question, it really does get tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put only the content of object, ie `6080604052336000806101...`.

The bytecode is only the part `6080604052336000806101...`, remix add extra info that MyEtherWallet doesn't know about.